# How to prove this comment of Fulton

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to understand why this is true in Fulton's *Algebraic Curves*:

[image]
[image]

Why we add this point $(0,\ldots, 0)$? Why this equality is true? I really need help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It appears as if $p$ stands for projective and $a$ stands for affine. Fulton needs to differentiate what space one takes the vanishing/ideal to be in, but I would agree if someone says that is confusing notation.

Comment: @RghtHndSd I'm sorry, I made a confusion, please see my edit.

Comment: Ah, I see. In case you are not aware, a cone with respect to a point p and a set S is the collection of all lines that go through (p,q) where q lies in S. Take S to be a circle lying somewhere above the origin in 3-space, and p to be the origin. You get a (double) cone.

Comment: Why do we add the point$(0,\dots,0)$? We have to add it to make the highlighted equation correct. Because $I$ is homogeneous (and not the whole ring), the point $(0,\dots,0)$ is in $V_a(I)$. To make the equation true, we'd better have $(0,\dots,0)$ in $C(V_p(I))$ also.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f\in\mathbb{K}[x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}]$ be homogeneous. Then $(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1})\in C(V_p(f))$ if and only if $[x_1:\ldots:x_{n+1}]\in V_p(f)$ if and only if $f(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1})=0$. This is it, I think.

Oh, there is also $p=(0,\ldots,0)$, of course, but since $f$ is homogeneous, $p\in V_a(f)$.

Comment: Why we add this point $(0,\ldots 0)$? it seems unnecessary.

Comment: A cone in $A^{n+1}$ needs to be invariant under multiplication by any scalar, for example.

Comment: A better answer: a point in $P^n$ represents a line in $A^{n+1}$. The cone over a subset in $P^n$ is the union of all corresponding lines in $A^{n+1}$. $0$ lies in all these lines, of course.